# Guest OS in Ubuntu 14.04 cannot access internet with NAT mode

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

In ubuntu 12.04, Vbox 4.2.30 there is no problem at all. However, in 14.04, the guest OS like win 7, win 8, win 10, cannot access internet. The guest OS can actually get the ip and ping the gateway without problem. But no internet access at all.

But, with bridge mode, it can access internet.

Comment: did you have the same problems with Virtualbox 4.2.28?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy I did not tried this with 4.2.28 in ubuntu-14.04